# Error when installing oracle-java7-installer

Tags: installation, java

I'm trying to install Java 7 on my Ubuntu 12.04. But everytime I try, it always shows error like below. This is when I'm trying to upgrade even when the Java 7 is not installed

```
harits@harits-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for harits: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  oracle-java7-installer
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u3-0~eugenesan~precise4) ...
Downloading...
--2012-07-14 17:53:46--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 111.94.254.10, 111.94.254.17
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|111.94.254.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz [following]
--2012-07-14 17:53:46--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 184.51.118.174
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|184.51.118.174|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2012-07-14 17:53:47--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|111.94.254.10|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz'

     0K .....                                                 100% 95.1M=0s

2012-07-14 17:53:47 (95.1 MB/s) - `./jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
harits@harits-ubuntu:~$
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: I dont understand are you trying to upgrade from 6 to 7 ?

Comment: At this point, I would just recommend using openJDK 7. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`, and/or `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, if you plan on developing java apps.

Answer (score 10):

Well looks like this is an old question but no one has answered it yet so...  better late than never I guess.  I've been ripping my hair out over this too.  Like you most boards just tell me too use open-jdk.  what most people don't seem to understand that open-jdk and jdk-7 are not one to one mappings of each other and many tools relied upon by developers simply don't work with open-jdk.  ANYWAY...

I found a solution which solved the problem for me.  Hopefully it will work for you.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer* 

sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java* 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Not working anymore in June 2018, as per @Ahmad's answer below https://askubuntu.com/a/956082/610009 They are not distributing java7 anymore

Answer (score 3):

As @Ahmad-sibai said

> "Recently, webupd8 team stopped distributing their installer for
>   Oracle java 7."

What you can do is to:

1. manually download them from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html and put them in cache if you have an Oracle Support account and you really need Oracle JDK 6 or 7.
2. Place them in the following folder:

   ```
   /var/cache/oracle-jdk6-installer/ for JDK 6 (you'll need version 6u45)
   /var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/ for JDK 7 (you'll need version 7u80 for 32bit and 64bit or 7u60 for arm)
   ```
3. Install again using the webupd8 installers

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
   ```

Comment: It throws: `Package oracle-java7-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source`

Answer (score 2):

Recently, webupd8 team [stopped distributing](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html) their installer for Oracle java 7.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Ben Glasser's answer, but it didn't work.

It tried the other answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955890/1198772, and it works.

We just need to download (manually) the latest jdk from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html, and replace the old jdk. Then try to install again.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Ben's answer while also addressing Ahmad's point:
Replace the following step in Bens answer:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

With:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer`

And if that doesn't work, just install the default version by running:

`sudo apt-get install default-jre`

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04